# Preflight CORS request fail on some versions of Firefox

Tags: firefox, cors, firefox-developer-tools

Using Firefox `45.8.0 ESR` on Windows.

Trying to load https://secure.scheduleonce.com/dana

The page doesn't load, and in the network panel I see a crossed padlock icon instead of green padlock icon for this request:

```
OPTIONS https://cfproxy.scheduleonce.com/get-data/GetLandingPageLayout
```

When floating over the padlock I see the following message:

> The connection used to fetch this request was not secure.

**The page loads fine on Chrome / Safari / IE and even more recent version of FF**.

Is there any way to debug what's wrong with that request to resource exactly ? FF doesn't give me any information as to what went wrong.

I suspect it might be related to the fact it's a preflight CORS request (the requested domain is different than that hosted page domain).

Attaching HAR file of the network : https://www.dropbox.com/s/i59k66a2w8p3ast/Archive%2017-09-10%2007-06-15.har?dl=0

Can be viewer here: (https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/har_analyzer)

Thanks.

Comment: Please note that the [current ESR version is 52.3.0](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/52.3.0/releasenotes/). So I suggest to update your browser and then check again if the issue persists.

Comment: @SebastianZartner The issue doesn't persist in the current version. That's why I posted it here in the first place, I don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

Problem was with the cipher suite choice on the server.

I used this site to change it:
https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/

To support older browsers as well.

I don't know what was in FF 45.8.0 ESR that made it not respect the security of the server.